# How to add ConcurrencyCheck to an entity generated via database first in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

I want to add a ConcurrencyCheck attribute to an entity property.

In the old Entity Framework you did this in the edmx file. How do you do it in Core?

I should add that I can see this isn't the recommended approach, however I would still like to know how to do it:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: [Concurrency Tokens - Configuring - Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/concurrency?tabs=fluent-api)

Comment: The "old" EF didn't use an edmx file since EF 4 introduced code first. The way to add a concurrency check hasn't changed since. The *recommended* way is to add a `rowversion ` column to the table, add a matching property to your entity and add the `Timestamp` attribute to it. Or you can use the Fluent API to add the column and specify it's used for concurrency checks with `.IsRowVersion()`

Comment: I'm missing something obvious here. When you update the database, and then run the scaffold command, both the entities and the DbContext child class are overwritten, which removes both the attributes and changes to the OnModelCreating method

Comment: If you can't do that, a less performant way is to specify the columns/properties to check for changes with the `ConcurrencyCheck` attribute. This is more expensive because it has to retrieve and check multiple attributes.

Comment: @tony you didn't ask about scaffolding. You asked about concurrency checks. Scaffolding understands `rowversion` already. You can control what gets generated by scaffolding, attributes or Fluent calls. The generated classes are partial, which means you can add extra methods in a different file that doesn't get auto-generated

Comment: I did say this was via database first, at my present limited level of knowledge that means scaffolding

Comment: I use database-first exclusively. Haven't used scaffolding for almost 10 years though. They aren't the same thing. As with EF Old, you can create your own partial files that won't be overwritten